# How to register a Twig Extension in services.yaml?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml, symfony-2.3

I use twig with Symfony2, and my project structure is:

```
/myprojectroot
    /app
        /config
            services.yml
        bootstrap.php
    /src
        /Foo
            /Bar
                /Util
                    myextension.php
```

I'm following [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) to create my extension, but I find that it's lacking details about namespaces, paths and the registration. I also went through the [detailed doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension) but it didn't help much.

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:  <---What is this line? Just a name? 
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension } <--- Should I ever change that?
```

My extension is defined as:

**edit: I corrected my getFunctions() according to Jason Roman's answer, but the error persist.**

```
namespace Foo\Bar\Util;        

class QrCodeHandler extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
                new \Twig_SimpleFunction('genqr', 'generateQRcode'),
        );
    }

    public function generateQRcode($data)
    {
        //snip code...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'qr_extension';
    }
}
```

and my services.yaml:

```
services:
  qr_extension:
        class: Foo\Bar\Util\QrCodeHandler
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

services.yml is loaded by bootstrap.php with this code:

```
$services = $parser->parse(__DIR__ . '/config/services.yml');

if (isset($services['services']))
{
    foreach ( $services['services'] as $name => $class )
    {
        $app['service.' . $name] = $app->share(function (Application $app) use($class) {
            $service = new $class($app);
            if (!$service instanceof ServiceInterface)
            {
                $errorMessage = get_class($service) . ' must implement ServiceInterface.';
                $app['monolog']->addError($errorMessage);
                throw new \Exception($errorMessage);
            }

            return $service;
        });
    }
}
```

Of course I'm asking because I'm getting an error

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "genqr" does not exist

so I wonder what's wrong. I suppose the problem is how I register it.

**Can someone explain me what are the various part of the registration code and what should I use for it to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your custom function incorrectly.  It should be this instead:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('genqr', array($this, 'generateQRcode')),
    );
}
```

This makes sure that the `generateQRcode` method is being called from within your class.  As to your other questions:

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:  <---What is this line? Just a name?
```

Yes that's just the name of the service.  Just make sure this name is unique.

```
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension } <--- Should I ever change that?
```

No you will never be changing that.  See the [Symfony documentation for tagged services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html).

Comment: I corrected my getFunctions(), but the error persist.

Comment: Does your `app/config/config.yml` load your `services.yaml` file?  (also change it to `services.yml` for consistency)

Comment: It doesn't, services are loaded in bootstrap.php, I'll add the code.

Comment: Are you on Symfony 2.3?  The bootstrap file is usually auto-generated as far as I can remember...as far as I can remember you might need to explicitly add `- { resources: "services.yml" }` to the `imports:` section at the top of your `app/config/config.yml` file

Comment: It doesn't exist at all?  Did you delete it?  It comes standard with your Symfony installation https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.3/app/config

Comment: For context, I've inherited the project from oversea, and I know php but not twig and symphony. The website somehow works though. I'll look at your link and shape it back up properly, thanks.